# Very long delay after simple php conditional statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php file which takes rows from a MySQL database, cuts out a specific portion of information and spits it out in different sections.  Each database entry has a timestamp applied to it which I use to sort them with.  The timestamp and actual content get separated by a "#" character when they are put in to the $sortholder variable.  After being sorted I use strstr to remove the useless time characters up to the #, and then substr to remove the # itself.  Since some database entries will not actually have a timestamp I want to remove these from the listing.  To do this I simply made a temporary variable to hold the substr of $sortholder from 0-2 and checked if ($temp != "0#").

This statement works and provides the correct output, but for some reason it causes a delay of up to 1 minute before processing.  If I remove the "if ($temp != "0#")", it goes instantly.  Why could such a simple conditional be causing such a long delay?

```
<?php
  include("dbsetup.php");
  $result = mysql_list_tables($dbname);
  $x=0;

  if (!$result)
  {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {
    // added code to use the tablename and select all records from that table
    $sql="select * from " . $row[0];
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die ('SQL problem selecting from table');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result2) >= 1)
    {
      while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
      {
        for ($i=7; $i<mysql_num_fields($result2); $i+=7,$x++)
        {
          $sortholder[$x] = $row2[$i+1]."#<b>".$row2[$i-3].
                            ":</b> <br><br><br>".$row2[$i]."<br><br>";
        }
      }
      sort($sortholder);

      while ($x >= 0)
      {
        $temp = substr($sortholder[$x], 0, 2);
        if ($temp != "0#")
        {
          $tempstr = strstr($sortholder[$x], "#");
          echo substr($tempstr, 1);
          echo ("<div id=\"bookbar\"></div><br><br>");
          $x--;
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo ("Guest book empty"); 
    }
    mysql_free_result($result2);
  }

  mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: You are aware that you are processing *all* entries from *all* tables in your database? That alone is hugely wasteful. If you only want a portion of the database, use SQL `WHERE` statements to filter **in the database**. Sorting should also be done by the database, not in PHP after the fact. I'd suggest you read a book about SQL first.

Comment: have u heard about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Yes, I do realize that this is terrible programming... I'm actually reading up on the subject right now.  At least for the time being, it is not "as" wasteful as it seems.  There is only one table for it to parse through anyway (and a fairly small one at that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it's not the condition itself that takes time, but the fact that `$x--` is not executed if `temp != "O#"`

So if `$temp = substr($sortholder[$x], 0, 2);` is equals to `"0#"`, it will go in an infinite loop.

Comment: Wow, i'm brilliant... This is what happens when I ignore sleep -.-  I'll accept that answer in 5 minutes, once it lets me.

Comment: I'd have expected an infinite loop from this, not a long delay.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of this line 
    $x--;
not being run most of the times. As the program exits loop only when $x<0 and $x gets decremented only when there is a timestamp.

So, apparently there are many fields without timestamp and hence the program is evaluating the if statement many a time before actually entering into it and decrementing the loop.